# Computing $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: limits

I need to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$$

How does the limit go to 0? Please show steps.

Comment: Have you tried converting the limit to polar coordinates?

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:* $$\dfrac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2} = \dfrac{1-\cos^2(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)\left(1+\cos(x^2+y^2)\right)} = \left(\dfrac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\right)^2\cdot\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{1+\cos(x^2+y^2)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $r^2=x^2+y^2$. So
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos r^2}{r^2}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{2r\sin r^2}{2r}=0,
$$
where I used L'Hôspital rule.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use Taylor series

> $$ \cos(t)=1-\frac{t^2}{2!}+\dots \implies 1-\cos(t)\sim \frac{t^2}{2!}. $$